# How to display data from database in the <p> using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to display the result of
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo '

'.$row.'

'
using the jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var row = <?php echo $row; ?>
    $(p).text(row);
</script>
```